# Delete row on tableview return incorrect row data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I've been trying to create a delete function to remove data and file from document directory all together then update the row data.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileURLs[indexPath.row])
        fileURLs.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        print(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        //tableView.reloadData()
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}
```

but every time I delete the file, it seems correctly get rid of the file from the directory, but the tableview seems incorrectly updated. for example

if I already have 1 file and delete it and create a new one the new one will always try to open the non-existed file by its name.

Comment: So, you are getting problem in creating a new file after deleting the existing file, right?

Comment: @PramodKumarSaxena yes, and also problem with the existing file as well after delete some files

Comment: how are you creating your fileURLs?

Comment: @PramodKumarSaxena load them from document directory as URL and append them into array

Comment: and whenever you use `FileManager` to delete the file firstly check that file exist or not, in your case if file doesn't exist your app will get crash. So try to use `try` with do block.

Comment: make sure that each file have unique name.

Comment: @PramodKumarSaxena do all that still get the same result, btw.

Comment: Please show your code for file naming! There might be issue with the file name so that you're unable to load the file back from Document directory.

Comment: @JameS Yes, if you are not making them unique.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati each files are manually named by myself which named it using alertviewcontroller from another VC, and the array is completely empty except I add any file into it

Comment: @PramodKumarSaxena I randomly named the file ie. [../.../../../ww.csv, ../.../../../asadasd.csv, ../.../../../wadwadwa.csv] this is what I get from the array

Comment: @JameS So this is the content of your `fileURLs` array. If yes then add the url of the path of document directory before the file name, if no then before deleting the check if exist or not and same when creating the new file. While creating the new file then check, if exist then firstly delete it.